# The argument 'name' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am getting the below errors. I tried googling the issue. But none of the post I have found have helped me.

EDIT:Per Henk's reply. the Table in question.

```
[Table("TransactionDetail")]
public partial class TransactionDetail
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long TransactionDetailId { get; set; }
    public string TransactionName { get; set; }
    public string TransactionValue { get; set; }

    public virtual OriginalTransaction OriginalTrans { get; set; }
}
```

The Other Partial.

```
public partial class TransactionDetail
{
    public Transaction trans;
}
```

More specifically the error occur when I use a LINQ "MyContext.SomeDB.Find(x)". (if this helps).

Some post that I have looked at that seems to fit my issue but not help me solve it are:

Connection String: (in .config file).

```
 <add name="TransactionEF" 
 connectionString="some connection string" 
 providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

[EDMX Connectionstring 'name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28023224/edmx-connectionstring-name)

[Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281133/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-source)

[Getting Error The argument 'nameOrConnectionString' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space with Azure Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047055/getting-error-the-argument-nameorconnectionstring-cannot-be-null-empty-or-con)

Here is my dbContext class.

```
public partial class TransactionEF : DbContext
{
    public TransactionEF()
        : base("name=TransactionEF")
    {
    }   
    ...
}

System.ArgumentException: The argument 'name' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space.
at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.TableAttribute..ctor(String name)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule pModule, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob, Int32* pcNamedArgs)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule module, IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor, IntPtr& blob, IntPtr blobEnd, Int32& namedArgs)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
at System.ComponentModel.ReflectTypeDescriptionProvider.ReflectGetAttributes(Type type)
at System.ComponentModel.ReflectTypeDescriptionProvider.ReflectedTypeData.GetAttributes()
at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.TypeDescriptionNode.DefaultTypeDescriptor.System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetAttributes()
at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.TypeDescriptionNode.DefaultTypeDescriptor.System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetAttributes()
at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptor.GetAttributes()
at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(Type type)
at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.TypeAttributeConfigurationConvention`1.<.ctor>b__1(Type t)
at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.TypeConventionWithHavingBase`1.ApplyCore(Type memberInfo, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.TypeConventionBase.Apply(Type memberInfo, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ConventionsConfiguration.ApplyModelConfiguration(Type type, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ConventionsConfiguration.ApplyModelConfiguration(Type type, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.NavigationPropertyMapper.Map(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, EntityType entityType, Func`1 entityTypeConfiguration)
at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.NavigationPropertyMapper.Map(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, EntityType entityType, Func`1 entityTypeConfiguration)
at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.NavigationPropertyMapper.Map(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, EntityType entityType, Func`1 entityTypeConfiguration)
at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.NavigationPropertyMapper.Map(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, EntityType entityType, Func`1 entityTypeConfiguration)
at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.MapTypes(EdmModel model)
at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)
at MyCompany... 
at MyCompany... 
at MyCompany...
```

Comment: Are you indeed using EDMX?  Maybe go trough the properties window and look for an empty Name (or EntityName, SetName, whatever)

Comment: Since the table name is the same as the class name, couldn't you just omit the `Table` annotation altogether?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.TableAttribute..ctor(String name)
```

You didn't post the relevant part of the code. It's not about this constructor.

Check out [TableAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.tableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

You should look for any `[Table]` or `[Table("")]` in your project.

Comment: I can't seem to find the .TableAttribute constructor.

Comment: @MyreVan You need to look at **all** entities, not just the one you're querying.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG, one of the other partials did not have anything in the [Table("")]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have an empty Foreignkey attribute like

```
[ForeignKey("")]
```

Please have a look.